# Minecraft - target player not assigned to a team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i wanna do somethin like:

> /spawnpoint @a[team=!red,team=!yellow] x y z

so anyone not on those 2 teams will have their spawnpoint set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `@a[team=!red,yellow]` won't parse properly.  It will treat the `yellow` as a separate selector argument, which is invalid.  Because of this, I'm pretty sure it'll select everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
@a[team=]
```

Will check for all players with no team.